# Opening a new terminal tab in OSX(Snow Leopard) with the opening terminal windows directory path

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh

I've been Googling for a while looking for a simple way to do this, and I can't find one.

I have a custom terminal environment set up (zsh) with various aliases and functions to make things easier. One thing I keep running into is that I will quickly APPLE-t to create a new tab and then type a command relative to the path of the terminal window I was just in. This invariably fails because the path of the new tab is ~/ instead of whatever I was just using!
Any ideas for a script to set the directory path of the new terminal tabs to the directory path of the opening tab?

Any help most appreciated.

Ian

Comment: Solution: switch to http://konsole.kde.org/ which does support preserving CWD into new tabs/windows.  :)

Comment: I wonder if there's some AppleScript solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so as is my way I am answering my own question again (well at least getting close to answering it anyway)

I have found a less verbose script to the one above (courtesy of [Dan Benjamin](http://twitter.com/danbenjamin)) that seems to do the trick, although both scripts output a similar error before successfully completing. I have dealt with that by adding **clear** to the end of the script so that's no big problem.

I say that I have nearly solved my own problem because my objective was to find a way to accomplish this with the Apple-t key command that has been burnt into my muscle memory as the shortcut for a new tab in anything, thanks to countless hours in various web browsers. The best I can manage with a script such as Dan's is t-return which isn't the biggest difference, but big enough that I will be slightly irked every time I issue said command. I know, I should let it go..... But I can't, which is probably how I got into this mess in the first place, endlessly fiddling with computers. I digress, here is the script I am using:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Make a new OS X Terminal tab with the current working directory.

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    PATHDIR=`pwd`
else
    PATHDIR=$1
fi

/usr/bin/osascript <<EOF
activate application "Terminal"
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "t" using {command down}
end tell
tell application "Terminal"
    repeat with win in windows
        try
            if get frontmost of win is true then
                do script "cd $PATHDIR; clear" in (selected tab of win)
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
EOF
clear
```

For completeness here is the error that gets spat out on the soliciting window if the trailing clear is omitted:

```
2009-10-20 01:30:38.714 osascript[20862:903] Error loading /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types:  dlopen(/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax" declares no loadable handlers.
tab 2 of window id 13942
```

Comment: This fails for me on Snow Leopard (10.6.8):

    line 25:  1371 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/osascript

Comment: @JohnKeyes & i0n, if you want a less verbose solution that works on Snow Leopard, you should give [Gavin's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7911097/768510) answer a looking at.

Answer (score 56):

I have a couple of scripts I use:

**dup** (New window with the working dir):

```
#!/bin/sh
pwd=`pwd`
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd $pwd; clear\"" > /dev/null
```

and **tup**  (New tab with the same working dir):

```
#!/bin/sh

pwd=`pwd`
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\"" \
    -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"t\" using {command down}" \
    -e "do script \"cd $pwd; clear\" in front window" \
    -e "end tell"
    > /dev/null
```

Comment: These are brilliant, there really aren't enough +1 for this answer. Thank you Gavin, simply brilliant.

Comment: Nice! I'm now using iTerm but I tried these out in Terminal and they work a treat.

Comment: Awesome, I slighlty modified it to take an argument. I use it to bootstrap my web projects environment now : https://gist.github.com/2492064

Answer (score 6):

One other solution without scripting is [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/), which has this feature built in. It has even more features that make it worth checking out too.

Comment: iTerm2 is so winful.  I don't know what I'd do without it.  Full-screen mode and screen-splitting is also a must-have feature.  I can't believe the applescript hoops that people are willing to jump through when iTerm2 makes this (and so many other essential things) so easy!

Comment: How does one accomplish this with iTerm2?

Comment: @mycargus Try this: iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> General -> Reuse previous session's home directory

Answer (score 4):

You can get what you want by modifying the BASH script found at [http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Mac+OS+X/2008/06/27/Terminal-Tricks-“term”-revisited-with-tabs](http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Mac+OS+X/2008/06/27/Terminal-Tricks-%E2%80%9Cterm%E2%80%9D-revisited-with-tabs.html).  Here is the script, taken from Marc Linyage's site [www.entropy.ch/blog](http://www.entropy.ch/blog).

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Open a new Mac OS X terminal window or tab in the current or another
# directory and optionally run a command in the new window or tab.
#
# - Without any arguments, the new terminal window opens in
#   the current directory, i.e. the executed command is "cd $PWD".
# - If the first argument is a directory, the new terminal will "cd" into
#   that directory before executing the remaining arguments as command.
# - The optional "-t" flag executes the command in a new tab 
#   instead of a new window.
# - The optional "-x" flag closes the new window or tab
#   after the executed command finishes.
# - The optional "-p" flag takes an argument of the form x,y (e.g. 40,50) and
#   positions the terminal window to the indicated location on the screen
# - The optional "-s" flag takes an argument of the form w,h (e.g. 800,400) and
#   resizes the terminal window to the indicated width and height in pixels.
#
# Written by Marc Liyanage <http://www.entropy.ch>
#
# Version 2.1
#

set -e

while getopts xtp:s: OPTION; do
    [ $OPTION = "x" ] && { EXIT='; exit'; }
    [ $OPTION = "t" ] && { TAB=1; }
    [ $OPTION = "p" ] && { POSITION="set position of window 1 to {$OPTARG}"; }
    [ $OPTION = "s" ] && { SIZE="set size of window 1 to {$OPTARG}"; }
done

for (( $OPTIND; $OPTIND-1; OPTIND=$OPTIND-1 )); do shift; done

if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then WD=$(cd "$1"; pwd); shift; else WD=$PWD; fi


COMMAND="cd '$WD' && echo -n \$'\\\\ec';"
for i in "$@"; do
COMMAND="$COMMAND '$i'"
done

if [ $TAB ]; then

osascript 2>/dev/null <<EOF
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
end
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script with command "$COMMAND $EXIT" in window 1
    $POSITION
    $SIZE
end tell
EOF

else

osascript <<EOF
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script with command "$COMMAND $EXIT"
    $POSITION
    $SIZE
end tell
EOF

fi
```

Comment: Huh.  I wonder what that silly `for (( ... ))` loop is for; `shift $OPTIND` would be much better.  Also, `COMMAND=...` should definitely be more like `COMMAND="cd $(printf '%q' "$WD") ..."` for safety.  Ah well, it seems reasonably clever regardless.

Answer (score 1):

In my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/54135/change-directory-cd-to-another-terminals-cwd/54161#54161), I provided a function and an alias:

```
function cd () { command cd "$@"; echo "$PWD" > /tmp/CWD; }
export cd

alias cdp='cd $(cat /tmp/CWD)'
```

You should be able to put a (possibly conditional) statement at the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` to execute that alias.

Comment: Not quite perfect, though.  Suppose you have two tabs open, your last `cd` was done in tab 1, but you're currently working in tab 2.  Now you spawn a new tab -- it goes to the CWD of tab 1, not the CWD of tab 2.

Comment: This breaks the cd command in my terminal. Not sure why, but I thought I'd better mention it for others benefit. Everything returns to normal upon removal. Thanks for your efforts though!

Comment: @ephemient: The `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable could be set to `'echo "$PWD" > /tmp/CWD'` so it's written every time a prompt is issued. @i0n: What exactly does "breaks" mean. Error message? Specific behavior?

Comment: Yes could have been more descriptive couldn't I! The cd command stops doing anything at all. No error message of any kind. cd .. cd DIR_NAME  cd ~ everything to do with cd stops working. A complete and up to date copy of all of my terminal related files is on GitHub here: http://github.com/i0n/dotfiles

Comment: You might try adding `export cd`

Comment: You might instead try (in Bash in any case) `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "$PWD" > /tmp/CWD'`

Comment: For `zsh`: PROMPT="$PROMPT\$(pwd>/tmp/ZWD)"