# Inquiry: How to convert this batch file to shell script?

Tags: perl, shell

I was given a batch file called make.bat with the following information:

```
javac Node.java
javac PhysServer.java
start java Physerver topology.txt 8080
start java Node A localhost 8080
start java Node B localhost 8080
```

Since I run OSX and linux, I cannot run batch files. Hence, how could I rewrite 
this as a perl script and run in terminal? I tried the following below but it crashes:

```
#!/user/bin/perl  
javac Node.java
javac PhysServer.java
start java Physerver topology.txt 8080
start java Node A localhost 8080
start java Node B localhost 8080
```

The error I get is:

```
Number found where operator expected at ./make2.pl line 5, near "txt 8080"
    (Do you need to predeclare txt?)
```

I also suspect that I should delete "start" in front of java and just invoke the java command. I am sorry about this silly question, but I am rusty with scripts in general and have been teaching myself how to write perl and makefiles lately to start saving time.

Also, when I have been searching for an answer, I mostly found posts talking about how to run perl in java, which is something I don't want to do. I thought that was something I could do with perl, but comments below corrected me. I'm learning and won't make the same mistake ever again. Thanks for all your posts. I will vote and comment on all.

Comment: This is not a perl script, but a shell script you want.

Comment: Thanks TLP. I'm learning. So I'll modify my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl is a complete programming language like Java. It's not the best choice for this. A bourne shell script would be easier:

```
#!/bin/sh
javac Node.java
javac PhysServer.java
java Physerver topology.txt 8080 &
java Node A localhost 8080 &
java Node B localhost 8080 &
```

If you want to add error checking,

```
#!/bin/sh
javac Node.java &&
javac PhysServer.java && (
   java Physerver topology.txt 8080 &
   java Node A localhost 8080 &
   java Node B localhost 8080 &
)
```

In a comment, you indicated you want to start each server in a new Window. I'm not an OS X user, so I had to look it up. Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589114/opening-a-new-terminal-tab-in-osxsnow-leopard-with-the-opening-terminal-window) suggests

```
#!/bin/sh
pwd="`pwd`"

javac Node.java &&
javac PhysServer.java && (
   osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd \\\"$pwd\\\"; clear; java Physerver topology.txt 8080\"" >/dev/null
   osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd \\\"$pwd\\\"; clear; java Node A localhost 8080\"" >/dev/null
   osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd \\\"$pwd\\\"; clear; java Node B localhost 8080\"" >/dev/null
)
```

Comment: Since you responded first, I gave you credit for the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the other guy beat me by a few seconds, but my answer actually gives the correct code (where his doesn't), and mine includes an improved version too!

Comment: Added a means of opening in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written resembles shell script far more than it does Perl.

```
#!/bin/sh

javac Node.java
javac PhysServer.java
java Physerver topology.txt 8080
java Node A localhost 8080
java Node B localhost 8080
```

I'm not familiar with batch scripts, so I can't tell if the three Java processes should run sequentially, waiting for one to complete before starting the next (which the above code does), or run in parallel. If in parallel, add an `&` to the end of each of the last three lines.

Comment: Is there script commands that allow you to print in a separate terminal screen?